# EC2 + RDSで構築したwordpressサイトにドメイン名でアクセスできない

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

タイトルの通り、EC２ + RDSでwordpressサイトを構築しています。
Route53でDNS設定を行いAレコードでALBのパブリックDNSを指定しました。

EC2やALBのパブリックDNSに対して直接アクセスすると表示されるのですが、ドメイン(`http://example.com`)にアクセスすると`Error establishing a database connection`と表示されてしまいます。

EC2サーバ内で`wp-config.php`の編集を行い、RDSのエンドポイントやDB名等の必要事項の設定は正しく行われているものと思います。

大変初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

必要な情報等ありましたら仰っていただければご提供致します。

Comment: EC2で実際に設定した手順を詳細に追記いただけると原因の調査がしやすいかもしれないです。たとえばhttpd.confの設定をこう変えた。wp-config.phpの設定をこうした。などですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
```
/** WordPress のためのデータベース名 */
define( 'DB_NAME', '〇〇' );

/** MySQL データベースのユーザー名 */
define( 'DB_USER', '〇〇' );

/** MySQL データベースのパスワード */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '〇〇' );

/** MySQL のホスト名 */
define( 'DB_HOST', '〇〇' );
```
こちらの〇〇の部分を変更しただけになります。

あ、httpd.confの内容変更してないですね...

Comment: 解決したのであれば、ぜひ[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をしてみてください。またアクセスログ等を確認すれば、文字通りDNSの浸透がきちんとされていたかどうかが確認できると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。仰る通り、アクセスログ等の確認を怠っていたことが原因でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

時間を置いたら無事表示されるようになりましたので、完全に理解しての解決ではなく気持ち悪さが残りました。
考えられる原因としては、今回、お名前ドットコムのレンタルサーバーからAWSへの移行だったのですが、恐らくDNSの変更が浸透していなかった、または何かしらのキャッシュの影響でサーバーの向き先が変わっていなかったものかと思います。

Comment: 切り分けの手順として、同一サーバ内からのcurl、同一セグメントないからのcurl外部ネットワークからの・・・と順に広げていくとよいですよ。気持ち悪さの解決の一助になれば。対象を絞っていって対策を考えてとやっていかないと、いつまでもおっしゃるような「気持ち悪い」状態は解決されません。再現性がなく、幽霊怖い状態で使うのもつらいじゃないですか。

Answer (score 0):

問題を切り分けるために、最小構成での動作確認を実施することをお勧めします。
たとえば、EC2インスタンスでcurl http://localhost にアクセスしたときの挙動。
ダイレクトにDBクライアントでDBに接続してみるなど、単体での動作は確認できていますか？

お話の内容から、HTTPサーバ、DB間の接続設定がうまくいってないのだろうと思われますが。。
たとえば、設定変更後にHTTPサーバのインスタンスの再起動など実施していますか？
設定後、設定の有効化を実施していないなども普通にあり得ますので、一度確認されてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 今回の場合、apacheで動かしているのですが、仰っているHTTPサーバというのapacheが該当しますでしょうか？

であれば、apacheのhttpd.confの設定は変更していないのでそこですかね...?